# PopOverController appears next to the selected cell

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working on a tableviewcontroller in `Xamarin.iOS` platform.

The following code works when user clicks on the second row in the first section in the tableview.

When user clicks, then popover view appears. However position of the popover does not appear just next to the selected cell. How could I handle it?

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
  if (indexPath.Row == 1 && indexPath.Section == 0) {
    var vc = new IViewController (this,ivc.iInfo);
    var nc = new NavigationController (vc);
    nc.PreferredContentSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF (200, 300);
    UIPopoverController popupoverController = new UIPopoverController (nc);
    popupoverController.PresentFromRect (tableView.Bounds, tableView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `tableView`, you should use selected cell as follows.

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
popupoverController.PresentFromRect (cell.Bounds, cell, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
```